# Polar equation of a shifted cardioid?

Tags: graphing-functions, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I am trying to find the equation (in polar form) of a cardioid shifted by an amount $x_0$ in the $x$ direction.

I tried converting $r=1+\cos(\theta)$ in Cartesian coordinates, add $x_0$ to the $x$ component, and convert back to polar. However the new $\theta$ no longer corresponds to the polar angle, so I don't know how to get a closed form $r=f(\theta)$.

Comment: I strongly suspect it is your homework... Here is **not** do my homework site.

Comment: I think there used to be a homework help tag. Maybe that's gone? Regardless, if you show your effort and just not ask a question with no context, some may help point out your errors or give you a shove in the right direction.

Comment: It is not a homework. What I tried just led to something messy and not worth mentioning, hence the short question, and as it is quite a basic problem I thought the problem statement alone would be OK. I'll add my attempt anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polar equations live poorly with translations.

From $\rho=f(\theta)$ you draw the Cartesian coordinates $(\rho\cos\theta,\rho\sin\theta)$, then after translation $(\rho,\cos\theta+x_0,\rho\sin\theta)$. Reverting to polar,

$$\rho'=\sqrt{(\rho\cos\theta+x_0)^2+(\rho\sin\theta)^2}=\sqrt{\rho^2+2\rho\cos\theta+x_0^2}$$

and

$$\tan\theta'=\frac{\rho\sin\theta}{\rho\cos\theta+x_0}.$$

In general it is not possible to invert the relation between $\theta$ and $\theta'$ and you must content yourself with polar parametric equations.